# How to extract only the pixels of an image where it is masked? (Python numpy array operation)

Tags: python, image, numpy, mask

I have an image and its corresponding mask for the cob as numpy arrays:

[image]

[image: mask]

The image numpy array has shape (332, 107, 3).

The mask is Boolean (consists of True/False) and has this shape as binary (332, 107).

```
 [[False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 ...
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]]
```

How can I get the color pixels of the cob (all pixels in the color image where the mask is)?

Comment: What have you tried? A simple conditional should do it, test for the colour of the mask if the test passes, add the pixels from the image.

Comment: `img[mask[..., None]]`?

Comment: I am new at programming. I tried setting all pixels of the image which are not in the mask at 0: img[mask==False]=0 but this did not work. You mean I should loop over every element in the array?

Comment: if I use img[mask[..., None]] I get this error: IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 2; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1

Comment: I think you want `cob = img * mask` because `False` evaluates to zero.

Comment: This works if I turn my img into grayscale (1 channel); however, I have 3 color channels which leads to this error: 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (332,107,3) (332,107)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the useful comment of M.Setchell, I was able to find the answer myself.

Basically, I had to expand the dimensions of the mask array (2D) to the same dimension of the image (3D with 3 color channels).

```
y=np.expand_dims(mask,axis=2)
newmask=np.concatenate((y,y,y),axis=2)
```

Then I had to simply multiply the new mask with the image to get the colored mask:

```
cob= img * newmask
```

And here just for visualization the result:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question of how to extract the pixels...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an array of the pixels, i.e. array with shape (n,3):

```
#assuming mask.shape = (h,w) , and mask.dtype = bool
pixels = img[[mask]]
```

and if you want to produce the image in your answer then simply do this:

```
cop = img.copy()
cop[mask] = 0
```